# A Generalisation of Holomorphness

Tags: real-analysis

A holomorphic function is a function for which there exists a derivation in $\Bbb{C}$. If you consider it as a real function $\Bbb{R}^2\to\Bbb{R}^2$, its jacobian is a scaled rotation matrix.

In this generalisation, let's call it $n$-holomorphness. An $n$-holomorphic function is a function $\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}^n$ for which the jacoiban is a scaled rotation matrix. The functions which we usually call holomorphic are 2-holomorphic in this generalisation. We know pretty much about 2-holomorphic function. I'm wondering how things go for $n>2$.

What I managed to discover is:

1. All constant functions are $n$-holomorphic.
2. Some linear functions are $n$-holomorphic but not all. Examples of 3-holomorphic functions are: $F(x,y,z)=(x,y,z)$, $F(x,y,z)=(y,z,x)$
3. Scaling an $n$-holomorphic function by a constant yields an $n$-holomorphic function.
4. For $n>2$, the set of $n$-holomorphic functions is not convex. For example $F(x,y,z)=(x,y,z)$ and $F(x,y,z)=(-x,-y,z)$ are both 3-holomorphic but $\frac{F}2+\frac{G}2$ is not.
5. If you take spherical inversion and negate one axis, you get an $n-$holomorphic function.
6. Analogues to Möbius transofrm are $n-$holomorphic functions. They can be created by composing rotations, translations, scalings and spherical inversions with one negated axis.

What I'm interested in:

1. Are there any $n-$holomorphic functions other than the ones which can be composed of rotations, translations, scalings and spherical inversions with one negated axis?
2. Is it possible to take any real function and extend it somehow to get an $n$-holomorphic function? And how many sollutions are there? More specially, I'm wondering how to extend the function $x^2$ to a 3-holomorphic function.

I found that the Jacobian of a 3-holomorphic function has to be in a form:
$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    a^2+b^2-c^2-d^2 & -2ad+2bc & 2ac+2bd \\
    2ad+2bc & a^2-b^2+c^2-d^2 & -2ab+2cd \\
    -2ac+2bd & 2ab+2cd & a^2-b^2-c^2+d^2 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
where $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ are arbitrary real functions. This leads to a set of differential equations but they seem to be too complicated.

Comment: I’m pretty sure you are looking for special cases of functions of several complex variables, or? (See this entry, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Several_complex_variables)

Comment: For example, a 3-holomorphic function is of the type $\Bbb{R}^3\to\Bbb{R}^3$. I don't see how several complex variables may apply here.

Comment: Okay, I’m not particularly suggesting that they’d be holomorphic in the sense of several complex variables, but that they’d be special cases of functions of several complex variables (In the case of $\mathbb{R}^3$, as you’re considering the rotation matrices, I’d even think they’d be special cases of functions of quarternion variables as well). But that’s just my thought upon reading through your examples.

Comment: The standard term is [conformal map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_map).

Comment: Thank you! If I read that correctly, it means that the answer to both questions is no. Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No and no.
Already answered [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/52209/3d-conformal-mappings).